# Copying a file from a directory to another one

Tags: vb.net, file-copying

I have a an application which is supposed to copy a selected file whose directory is written in txtbox1 to a folder of director written in txtbox2 as follows :

code :

```
Dim sourcepath As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim DestPath As String = TextBox2.Text
    CopyDirectory(sourcepath, DestPath)
```

Called sub:

```
Private Shared Sub CopyDirectory(ByVal sourcePath As String, ByVal destPath As String)
    If Not Directory.Exists(destPath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath)
    End If
    For Each file__1 As String In Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(sourcePath))
        Dim dest As String = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(file__1))
        File.Copy(file__1, dest)
    Next
    For Each folder As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Path.GetDirectoryName(sourcePath))
        Dim dest As String = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(folder))
        CopyDirectory(folder, dest)
    Next
End Sub
```

This code copies all the files, not the specified one only. Can someone please tell me how to make this sub copy only the selected file not all the files in the folder?

Comment: There is nothing there to select anything. Selected *how - is the user supposed to select them?  Please clarify and read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: what are selected file(s)? there's nowhere any kind of array of, let say, selected file(s)

Comment: Thanks for the remark I've updated my question, hope it provides enough information now.

Comment: @ahmedseif Your question still doesn't really indicate how the user is selecting which file they want to copy. Do you have a variable storing the filename to copy?

Comment: The directory of the file is in txtbox1 and the folder's directory (which the file will be copied to) is in textbox2, The first textbox gets it's value from an open file dialog and the second one from a folder browser dialog. I thought it'd be okay just to know that the two directories are stored in txtbox1 and txtbox2 values didn't have in mind that i'd matter how the user is going to select  the files.

Answer (score 1):

You're taking the entire path as an argument (something like this: C:/someDirectory/filename.txt) and aren't comparing the filename to the other filenames in that directory.

Instead of using:

```
For Each file__1 As String In Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(sourcePath))
    Dim dest As String = Path.Combine(destPath, Path.GetFileName(file__1))
    File.Copy(file__1, dest)
Next
```

Try:

```
Dim sourceFileName = Path.GetFileName(sourcePath)
For Each filePath As String in Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(sourcePath))
    Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(filePath)
    If sourceFileName = filename
    'Do your copy code here
    End If
Next
```

Comment: It would probably be better to use the [Path.GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) method for extracting the name of a file from a path, as opposed to manually splitting the string yourself.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I don't usually work with file names, so I wasn't sure what methods Path had.